# Adding list depending on a variable

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I want to add a list to another list. That's not hard, I did it with `list = list + test1;`, but the problem is that I want to add another list depending on a variable.

To give you an instance: if a String is test1, than I want to add the `test1` list, if the variable is test2 than the `test2` list and so on. I have the lists `test1`, `test2`, `test3`,... hardcoded (see below). I tried the code `list = list + listVariable`, but it doesn´t work.

`listVariable` is a String which can be changed by the user by a textfield. For example, when the user enters test2 in the textfield than the list `test2` should be added to the list `list`. The problem is that I can´t hardcode it like `if (listVariable == test2) {list = list + test2}`, because I have too many lists. If I haven't described my issue good enough, please let me know.

That are my lists:

```
var test1 = [
  {"name": "test1.1", "time": 10},
  {"name": "test1.2", "time": 10},
];

var test2 = [
  {"name": "test2.1", "time": 10},
  {"name": "test2.2", "time": 10},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try mapping the values like this:

```
    // INPUT FROM USER TEXT FIELD
    String listVariable;

    var list1 = [
      {"name": "test1.1", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test1.2", "time": 10},
    ];

    var list2 = [
      {"name": "test2.1", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test2.2", "time": 10},
    ];

    Map<String, List> map = {
      'test1': list1,
      'test2': list2,
    };

    if (map[listVariable] != null) {
      var list = list + map[listVariable];
    } else {
      print("User dont match any list values");
    }
```